# Does bitcoin.conf expand environment variables?

Tags: passphrase, bitcoin.conf

I would like to store my Bitcoin RPC passwords and usernames in environment variables, like:

> ```
> rpcuser=$RPC_USER
> rpcpassword=$RPC_PASSWORD
> ```

Is this supported in bitcoin core? Can environmental variables be parsed from my bitcoin.conf file?

Comment: Very bad idea! Why should you do such a thing?

Comment: Why is it a bad idea?

Comment: I don't think this is a bad idea, but I *do* think that this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: This would be great to have. I use docker to host my bitcoin node and I would like to be able to have docker inject environment variables depending on production/dev etc. Have you found how to do this yet?

Comment: It's been awhile. At the time, I ended up generating the config file with the values rather than using envvars, as I found no other way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, bitcoin core does not expand environment variables in `bitcoin.conf`.

See [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/0.19/src/util/system.cpp#L812) to see how options are parsed.

You can expand environment variables as arguments for `bitcoind`:

```
$ bitcoind -rpcuser="$RPC_USERNAME" -rpcpassword="$RPC_PASSWORD"
```